# Unable to parse dynamic content with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, jsoup

I'm practicing and trying to parse behance.net to retrieve .jpg files.

First, I tried with JSOUP, but I only receives and JS code without any useful code. Then i tried with selenium:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "S:\\behance-id\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.behance.net/gallery/148589707/Hercules-and-Randy");
String str = driver.getPageSource();
```

And I got same result. Through Google Chrome inspect option I found what I need:
[image]
But I cannot acces to this source page via Selenium and JSOUP and other instruments.
I only receive this with `<script>` tags:
[image]
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

That page is loading its resources dynamically, after the original HTML, so you should use waits in Selenium. This is the Java example for waiting an element to be loaded in page, from the documentation:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com/ncr");
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("cheese" + Keys.ENTER);
// Initialize and wait till element(link) became clickable - timeout in 10 seconds
WebElement firstResult = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a/h3")));
// Print the first result
System.out.println(firstResult.getText());
```

The documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

Comment: Tried with `By.xpath("//div[@class='ImageElement-root-kir ImageElement-loaded-icR']"`, method getText() returns nothing

Comment: That element has no text in it. It has an image though, and that image has all sorts of attributes.  You may amend your locator like so `By.xpath("//div[@class='ImageElement-root-kir ImageElement-loaded-icR']/img")`, and try to get that image's attributes, like src for example, or 'alt'.